# Linq to SQL in C# Unique data

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

[image: List problem]

I have a long list with ships that I get from a Linq to SQL query, but I only want one row per ImoNo. Today i have about 4 rows per ImoNo. I just need the one row that has been last updated (so in this example I need 2013-01-27).

This is my Linq To SQL query:

```
var res = from positions in context.Lloyds_ETAs
          join vessels in context.Lloyds_Vessels on positions.ImoNumber equals vessels.imo_no
           select new PositionData {
              ImoNo = positions.ImoNumber,
              PositionCordinates = positions.AIS_Latest_Position,
              CompassOverGround = positions.Compass_over_Ground_Heading,
              VesselId = positions.Vessel_ID,
              Equipment = vessels.vessel_type,
              Updated = positions.Last_Place_Location
           };

return res.ToList();
```

Comment: oh, [group](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-Grouping-c62703ea) maybe?

Comment: You want last updated row per ImoNr ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var res = (from positions in context.Lloyds_ETAs
          join vessels in context.Lloyds_Vessels on positions.ImoNumber equals vessels.imo_no
          select new PositionData {
              ImoNo = positions.ImoNumber,
              PositionCordinates = positions.AIS_Latest_Position,
              CompassOverGround = positions.Compass_over_Ground_Heading,
              VesselId = positions.Vessel_ID,
              Equipment = vessels.vessel_type,
              Updated = positions.Last_Place_Location
           })
           .GroupBy(x => x.ImoNo)
           .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(pd => pd.Updated).First());
```

Comment: This is probably correct, but I think this will generate one SQL statement per group using Linq2SQL.

Comment: @Magnus And I think this is exactly what the OP wants, as he said: `but I only want one row per ImoNo`.

Comment: Yes, this will give the correct result, but I think the SQL generated by linq2SQL will be one statement for each group. (very slow) But I haven't tested it so could be wrong.

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect and fast!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last one, all you have to do is append `.OrderBy(pd => pd.Updated).Last()` after your select.

```
var res = (from positions in context.Lloyds_ETAs
          join vessels in context.Lloyds_Vessels on positions.ImoNumber equals vessels.imo_no
           select new PositionData {
              ImoNo = positions.ImoNumber,
              PositionCordinates = positions.AIS_Latest_Position,
              CompassOverGround = positions.Compass_over_Ground_Heading,
              VesselId = positions.Vessel_ID,
              Equipment = vessels.vessel_type,
              Updated = positions.Last_Place_Location
           }).OrderBy(pd => pd.Updated).Last();

return res.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(yourQuery).OrderByDescending(pd=>pd.Updated).First()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to get just one "row" as a result:

```
res.OrderByDescending(x => x.Updated).Take(1);
res.OrderByDescending(x => x.Updated).First();
res.Order(x => x.Updated).Last();
```

It seems that you have some duplication though, so maybe doing a group by would be more appropriate.